# LDAP search filter in php : cannot exclude OU from the string search

Tags: php, filter, ldap

Newbie here. I recently started coding (HTML, CSS, JS, PHP...) and I'm having a little problem with LDAP searches, and especially with filters.

In order to create a site that will look for information in an Active Directory, I have set up a search bar that searches in users registered in AD, in order to return the results. But I would like to exclude certain OUs from this search, including the users present in them.

Here is my code:

```
            $nom = $_POST['nom'];
            $base_dn = "DC=TOTO, DC=COM";
            $filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenname=*$nom*)(sn=*$nom*))(!(ou=USERS)(ou=TEST)))";
            $attributes = ["sn", "givenname", "mail"];

            $search_result = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $filter, $attributes);

            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $search_result);

            $results = [];

            if ($entries['count'] === 0) {
                echo "Pas de résultats";
            } else {
                foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                    if (isset($entry['cn'][0])) {
                        $result = [
                            'sn' => isset($entry['sn'][0]) ? $entry['sn'][0] : ' ',
                            'givenname' => isset($entry['givenname'][0]) ? $entry['givenname'][0] : ' ',
                            'mail' => isset($entry['mail'][0]) ? $entry['mail'][0] : 'Non renseigné',
                        ];
                        array_push($results, $result);
                    } else {
                      echo " ";
                    }
                }

                ldap_unbind($ldap_conn);
```

The search works fine, but despite the exclusion of OUs in the filter, the search still displays the users present in the excluded OUs and whose sn/givenname correspond to the searched string.

I specify that I do this in PHP, and from scratch, without framework.

Any ideas ?

I tried a lot of filters, with no results. I don't know if it's my syntax that's wrong, or something else.

```
// I didn't have high hopes for that.
$filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenname=*$nom*)(sn=*$nom*))(!(memberOf=OU=Users,OU=USERS SERVEURS)))";

$filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenname=*$nom*)(sn=*$nom*))(!(ou=USERS))(!(ou=TEST)))";
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot exclude OUs in an LDAP filter - at least not in Active Directory.

There is no `ou` attribute, so `(!(ou=USERS))(!(ou=TEST))` means nothing at all. There are two attributes that would have the OU, but you can't use either:

1. `distinguishedName` would *contain* the DN of the OU, but you cannot do partial matches on any DN attribute.
2. [`msDS-parentdistname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/d4491b27-3b20-4cdf-b384-156f0f818c63) is the DN of the OU, but it is a constructed attribute (only returned if you specifically ask for it), and constructed attributes cannot be used in search filters.

So you have two options:

1. Exclude them *after* the results are returned. In your `$attributes`, ask for either `distinguishedName` or `msDS-parentdistname` and inside your `foreach`, check if one of those attributes contains the DN of the OU, and if so, `continue;`.
2. Only search the OUs you want. Do this by setting the `$base_dn` to the OU, and repeat for each OU you want to search. If you want to exclude sub-OUs, then use [`ldap_list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-list.php) instead of `ldap_search`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer !

> There is no ou attribute, so (!(ou=USERS))(!(ou=TEST)) means nothing at all. There are two attributes that would have the OU, but you can't use either:

That's strange, because there's an attribute named "ou" in the list in my Active Directory.

[attribute list image in ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6YRw.png)

I assume this is an exception (or else), but I supposed it was indeed an attribute by seeing it in the list. My mistake.

I actually found one of the options you suggested shortly after posting here. But I was still a bit curious if I could still exclude the OUs.

I share here the code I wrote before closing. My code is still a bit messy but i'm getting better !

```
$filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenname=*$nom*)(sn=*$nom*)))";
$attributes = ["cn", "sn", "dn", "givenname", "mobile"];
$excluded = ['OU=USERS', 'OU=Microsoft', 'OU=TEST', 'OU=System', 'OU=SERVEURS'];

$search_result = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $filter, $attributes);

$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $search_result);

$results = [];

if ($entries['count'] === 0) {
    echo "Pas de résultats";
} else {
  $all_excluded = true;
  foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if (isset($entry['cn'][0])) {
      $dn = $entry['dn'];
      $excluded_entry = false;
        foreach ($excluded as $excluded_dn) {
          if (strpos($dn, $excluded_dn) !== false) {
            $excluded_entry = true;
            break;
          }   
        } 
        
        if (!$excluded_entry) {
            $result = [
                'sn' => isset($entry['sn'][0]) ? $entry['sn'][0] : ' ',
                'givenname' => isset($entry['givenname'][0]) ? $entry['givenname'][0] : ' ',
                'mobile' => isset($entry['mobile'][0]) ? $entry['mobile'][0] : 'Non assigné'
              
            ];
            array_push($results, $result);
            $all_excluded = false; 

        } else {
          echo " ";
        }
    } else {
      echo " ";
    }
    }
```

Thanks again for your answer !